# http request not working in nested async Task<T> methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, httprequest

I'm working with async tasks for the first time, and I'm confronted with a problem I can't seem to solve.

i've got a method to call an API using a Http request.

```
internal static async Task<HttpResponse> CallAPI(string objectname, string parameters, HttpMethod method)
    {
        HttpResponse r = new HttpResponse();

        using (r.HttpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            r.HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://" + Properties.Settings.Default.APIURL + "/");
            r.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            r.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd+json;version=1");

            r.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", Properties.Settings.Default.APIURL);
            r.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Expect", "100-continue");
            r.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Close");

            switch (method)
            {
                case HttpMethod.DELETE:
                    using (r.ResponseMessage = await r.HttpClient.DeleteAsync("api/" + objectname.ToString() + "/" + parameters))
                    {
                        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        r.responseTime = Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                        r.ResponseData = await r.ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return r;
                    }

                case HttpMethod.GET:
                    using (r.ResponseMessage = await r.HttpClient.GetAsync("api/" + objectname.ToString() + parameters))
                    {
                        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        r.responseTime = Convert.ToInt32(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                        r.ResponseData = await r.ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return r;
                    }
                default: throw new Exception("No HTTP Method Found");
            }
        }
```

I call a delete() method in the class from a button click event:

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Activity a = new Activity();
        a.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtObjectId.text);
        //a.Delete(); //void method
        bool done = a.Delete().Result; //Task<bool> method
    }
```

if I make the delete() method a void, it works fine and returns the http response

```
public async virtual void Delete()
    {
            HttpResponse r = new HttpResponse();
            r = await CallAPI(_Objectname.ToString(), _Id.ToString(), HttpMethod.DELETE);                         
    }
```

but if I try to make Delete() a Task,

```
     public async virtual Task<bool> Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponse r = new HttpResponse();
            r = await CallAPI(_Objectname.ToString(), _Id.ToString(), HttpMethod.DELETE);                
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

it tries to execute the httpclient.deleteasync method and the app just doens't do anything. I don't get an exception, it doens't freeze, it just doens't seem to do anything anymore.

I have no idea what's causing this behavior, but I'm fairly new to async programming, so I'm probably doing something which I'm not supposed to :-)

Comment: How are you calling `Delete()`? I bet you are deadlocking yourself, that is why the `async void` worked. ([You should never do `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) btw unless you are writing a function that will be a event handler)

Comment: the delete method is part of a class object.

   `activity a = new activity();
    a.id = 12345;
    a.delete();`

and activity inherits `delete() `from a baseclass

Comment: So you just call `a.Delete()`, you don't call `await a.Delete()` or `a.Delete().Result` or `a.Delete().Wait()`? Also, your code is not inheriting, you are doing `public async virtual Task<bool> Delete()`, if it was inheriting from a base class it would be `public async override Task<bool> Delete()`

Comment: no i do call `await a.delete()`

Comment: That is likely your problem, if a exception is being thrown you won't be told about it if you don't do `await a.delete()`. And if you are trying to do it from the `void` version you would need to do `public async virtual Task Delete()` instead. As I said before, you should never be doing `async void` unless your function is a event handler.

Comment: but i am calling with `await`, and i also tried `delete().result`.
all have the same outcome

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said *"I do **not** call `await a.delete()`"*. You need to update your question, **the problem you are having is not in the code you have shown us**. You need to show your call stack all the way up the chain till you get to framework code. If you have a `.Result` or a `.Wait()` anywhere in the chain leading up it will cause this problem.

Comment: I've updated my question, but except for the button click eventhandler, there's nothing more to the callstack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `.Result` or `.Wait()` on code that uses async/await [you will deadlock your program](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), you must make your event handler `async void`, this is the only place you are allowed to use `async void`.

```
protected async void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Activity a = new Activity();
    a.Id = Convert.ToInt32(txtObjectId.text);
    //await a.Delete(); //Task method
    bool done = await a.Delete(); //Task<bool> method
}
```

And in case you do end up using the version that does not return `Task<bool>` the `Delete()` function would look like

```
public async virtual Task Delete()
{
        HttpResponse r = new HttpResponse();
        r = await CallAPI(_Objectname.ToString(), _Id.ToString(), HttpMethod.DELETE);                         
}
```

you do not need a `return` statement.

Also, if you don't need to access the UI, add `.ConfigurateAwait(false)` to each await call to make it not force the UI thread for it's continuations.

```
public async virtual Task Delete()
{
        HttpResponse r = new HttpResponse();
        r = await CallAPI(_Objectname.ToString(), _Id.ToString(), HttpMethod.DELETE).ConfigureAwait(false);                         
}
```

You can do the same to `CallAPI` too to make it run better.